# solr - Getting xyz present in DataConfig does not have a counterpart

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 5.2.
I did the following:

1. `solr create -c demo`
2. copied and placed the **schema.xml** in `demo/conf` folder. 
   I added a field called `load_date` as follow:

```xml
<field name="load_date" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

3. the data config looks like this

```xml
<document name="xyz">
  <entity name="input" query="select * from test" logLevel="debug" datasource="mbdev">
    <field column="LOAD_DATE" name="load_date" />
  </entity>
</document>
```

Only the `id` field is getting populated and is complaining that the field `load_date` present in DataConfig does not have a counterpart in Solr Schema. I checked my changes against example-DIH and could not see any difference.

I also noticed that the **Schema Browser** lists only the following fields:

- `text`
- `version`
- `id`
- `title`

I do not know which **schema.xml** it is referring to. How can I find this out?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the *solrconfig* was using '***managed-schema.xml***'.

Here is [the wiki documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Schema+Definition+in+SolrConfig) that explains the Managed Schema. I got it working after updating the managed-schema with field names.

If you want to work with *Schema.xml* ('ClassicIndexSchemaFactory') instead of *managed-schema.xml* then the following fieldtypes need to be added to the schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="tdates" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="tlongs" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="tdoubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to follow the type format ie add _s for string etc

See below the name and description fields, using that you don't need to touch schema file, it will map the fields types using this convention.

```
  <document name="Reports">
<entity name="Report" dataSource="ds1" pk="id"
  query = "select * from dbo.Roles">
    <field column="RoleID" name="id"/>
<field column="RoleName" name="name_s"/>
<field column="Description" name="description_t"/>
</entity>
```